# What exactly are Classes?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

As of now, I understand classes to be introduced for us to meaningfully talk about collections of object for which describing them with sets would create problems. I have a few questions about classes to help me understand them:

Traditionally, classes can only be collections of sets, never other classes, so It seems collections of classes cannot be spoken of in NBG set theory. Is this true?

Does there exist some set theory or system which allows you talk about absolutely every collection of objects you can conceive of without contradiction?

I know these are more philosophical then usual, but thanks for the help.

Comment: In NGB, a set is defined to be a class $S$ such that there exists a class $T$ with $S\in T$. That means you cannot have a class whose elements are **proper** classes (classes thar are not set), because being elements of a class automatically makes them sets. (Your entire posts uses “class” where you mean “proper class”)

Comment: Note also that in NGB “class” is a primitive notion, which has no definition, much like “set” has no definition in ZF Set Theory.

Comment: in NGB, are there anyways to make paradoxes concerning proper classes like Russell's paradox in naive set theory? Furthermore, Is there a system where you can specifically talk about collections of proper classes? Or is it the case that no theory will let you talk about all conceivable collections of objects without contradiction?

Comment: No; you cannot construct Russell’s paradox in NGB (if you could, we wouldn’t be using it!). Unlimited comprehension is known to lead to contradictions, so no, you cannot create an axiomatic theory in which unlimited comprehension (the ability to “talk about all conceivable collections of objects”) that is not inconsistent.

Comment: oh, ok, Interesting. Could we not do some infinite axiomtization which creates more and more general notions of set such that every given notion of a collection can always be explained in terms of a more general notion of collection? What is wrong with this?

Comment: You can think of class as a property that can be expressed with the language of set theory, I guess...

Comment: @Connor: That was the essence of Russell and Whitehead’s theory; there is no inherent problem (though it is still subject to Goedel’s Theorem); however, it does not allow you to talk about “all conceivable collections of objects”, because any statement you make can only be made about a bounded type of object.

Comment: The point of NGB and all other axiomatizations of set theory is precisely that you can't just introduce **any** concept in the theory, there have to be rules on what is allowed. The paradoxes prove that an unrestricted idea of class leads to contradictions, so any theory will have to impose some restrictions.